# How do i switch pairs of strings in an arraylist?

Tags: java, string, methods, collections, arraylist

How would i flip each pair of values in a list?
For example, If i have an arraylist 
["aa"", "bb"", "cc"", "DDD", "happy", "snow"].
 and wanted to the list afterwards to store ["bb"", "a"", "DDD", "cc"", "snow", "happy"]

I tried using a for loop but didnt get anything when i called the method.

```
 public static void flip2(ArrayList<String> list){


 for(int i =0; i <list.size(); i++){

 Collections.swap(list. i, (i+1){
 System.out.println("The new list = " + list));
    }
  }
}
```

I appreciate the help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just increment your index by 2 each time and swap element at index `i` and `i + 1`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  List<String> list = Arrays.asList("aa", "bb", "cc", "DDD", "happy", "snow");

  for(int i =0; i<list.size(); i+=2){
       Collections.swap(list, i, (i+1));
  }
  System.out.println("The new list = " + list);
}
```

Output :

```
The new list = [bb, aa, DDD, cc, snow, happy]
```

Note that this assume that your list have even number of objects into it.

If you want to handle all possible cases (whatever is the `size()` of the list) you can check that at each iteration, if `(i+1)` is inferior than the size.

```
for(int i =0; i+1<list.size(); i+=2){
    Collections.swap(list, i, (i+1));
}
```